# Loadrunner Vugen: How to save the Replay Summary Results that is displayed in Vugen as a csv/excel/tabular report?

Tags: load-testing, performance-testing, loadrunner, protocols

I have created a script in Loadrunner TruClient protocol and would like to run the script in Vugen and view the results now and then. This is to measure any changes in UI rendering time for every new build. (I don't want to upload the scripts to Performance Center and run load test and view the results in Analysis tool).

I see an option to export to PDF but it doesn't help as the table formatting in PDF is not good and I cannot use it for comparison. I find a transaction details.db file in local script folder but it needs SQLLite browser tool to open the file. So I would like to know if there is any default/easy option to export the Replay Summary results to csv/excel file formats?

Vugen Version: 2022R2 Build 381

[image: Replay Summary]